# Question on violation of uncertainty principle of lowest energy state when radial position and polar angle fixed

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Consider the case where, in 3-dimensions, a particle is free to move with potential energy equal to zero.  Furthermore, consider the case in which the radial position and the polar angle is fixed; this means that the particle is confined to move along the azimuthal angle.  Schrodinger's equation will then become:
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2\theta} \frac{d^2 \psi}{d \varphi^2} = E \psi$$

The solutions will be given by:

$$\psi(\varphi) = e^{in\varphi} \quad \text{with} \quad n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2, \ldots$$

In the case of $n=0$, doesn't this violate Heisenberg's uncertainty principle? The particle does not have an angular momentum yet it seems to me that the particle is confined to a specific region of space.

Comment: Please use mathjax instead of posting images of equations. Mathjax is better because it is 1) Searchable, 2) Editable, and 3) easier to read. I edited the post for you.

Comment: I think you'd better write down the uncertainty principle and evaluate the terms yourself. If you're still confused, then at least you'll have a more precise question :-)

Comment: @DanielSank well... when energy is zero, the particle is stationary.  However, it is still confined to be within the "ring".  Doesn't this automatically violate Heisenberg's uncertainty principle?

Comment: A quantum particle never has zero energu